# Efeito ':hover' com 'transform' apresenta defeito no Google Chrome quando sai do ':hover'

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-hover

Criei um efeito *hover* que dá um zoom `scale(1.5)` na imagem, porém quando ele sai do *hover* o `border-radius` da imagem torna a deixar a imagem quadrada antes de retornar a `border-radius` original. O problema só acontece no Chrome e Safari. Segue o meu código abaixo:

```css
.hoverzoom {
 position: relative;
    min-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.hoverzoom > img {
   width: 100%; 
 border-radius: 8px;
 -webkit-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
      -ms-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
          transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
}
.hoverzoom:hover > img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
      -o-transform: scale(1.5);
         transform: scale(1.5);
}
.hoverzoom .retina{
 position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;    
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(31, 124, 43, 0.5);    
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
 
    -webkit-transition:  all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
      -ms-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
          transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000); 
}
.hoverzoom:hover .retina {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverzoom"> 
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aipDU.jpg">
 <a href="#">
  <div class="retina"></div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Alguém sabe dizer o que está de errado?

Comment: Adicione também o código HTML à sua pergunta para que possamos recrear isto.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ot1jp4b5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto acontece porque durante a transição (`transition`) os elementos `child` não são "mascarados". Mas no final da transição, a situação já se torna OK novamente.

> Este é um bug conhecido em navegadores baseados em Webkit
>   [border-radius clipping without a stacking context does not apply to composited children](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218)

Podes resolver este problema de duas formas, adicionando um `z-index` positivo, por exemplo `z-index:1;` ou um `transform: translateZ(0);` no elemento *wrapper*. Aqui está um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.zoomTransition {
    -webkit-transition:  all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
        -moz-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
         -ms-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
          -o-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
             transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
}
.hoverzoom {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
    z-index:0;
}
.hoverzoom img {
   width: 100%; 
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.hoverzoom:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
         -o-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
}
.hoverzoom .retina{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;    
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(31, 124, 43, 0.5);    
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
.hoverzoom:hover .retina {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverzoom" style="margin:auto"> 
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/250/250/city" class="img-responsive center-block zoomTransition">
    <a>
        <div class="retina zoomTransition"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

> Fiz também alguns ajustes no código CSS, removendo a segunda adição de transições que era desnecessário e apontar estilos à imagem de uma maneira mais prática.

Comment: A entendi você agora. Muito bom, não sabia desse problema com Webkit. Muito obrigado parceiro, problema resolvido! Os ajustes também tão legais!

Comment: De nada amigo @FernandoS.Souza . Sempre pronto para ajudar ;) E essa é uma boa pergunta para estar aqui documentada, não sei porque tinham negativado a principio.

Comment: @FernandoS.Souza Considere marcar a minha resposta como correta para a destacar mais para os novos visitantes que estejam com o mesmo problema e procuram uma solução.

Comment: Já marquei como correta. E mais uma vez obrigado por sua ajuda! :P